# eBay API upload TrackingId by Sold listing | Sales record

Tags: asp.net, ebay-api

For Uploading Tracking Numbers to eBay via API I use [CompleteSale](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/CompleteSale.html) function, where I pass `OrderId` or `TransactionId`, but sometimes I don't have neither `TransactionId` nor `OrderId`, I just have `Sold listing | Sales record`

it looks like:

```
Sold listing | Sales record 123456
```

How can I upload tracking number used `Sold listing | Sales record` value? Should I first get `TransactionId` or `OrderId`?

Appreciate any help. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that case you need to use call for [GetSellingManagerSoldListings](http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/XML/docs/Reference/eBay/GetSellingManagerSoldListings.html)

then get SaleRecord array, which contains Transactions arrays. There is TransactionID in each transaction item.